# How to effectively float an image or background image

Tags: css, image, css-float, background-image, css-position

I need to dynamically display 2 graphic image files that represent opening and closing quotes as shown below in the sample screen shot.

The quotes need to appear just to the left and to the right of the upper content block as shown. Content block widths will vary on the page.

I have tried float and background image. Does anyone have a tip or trick to properly, dynamically and flexibly position 2 image files?

Here is what I have so far after working with @Utkanos answer:

**HTML**

```
<div class="postsPage_item_content postsPage_item_quote"><?php the_content();?></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#maincontentcontainer div#primary div div.postsPage_item_content {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
div#maincontentcontainer div#primary div div.postsPage_item_quote::before, div#maincontentcontainer div#primary div div.postsPage_item_quote::after {
  background-image: url('../images/QUOTE1.png');
  content: '';
  display: block;
  left: 20%;
  height: 28px; /* background-image natural height is 28px */
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 36px; /* background-image natural width is 36px */
}
div#maincontentcontainer div#primary div div.postsPage_item_quote::after {
  background-image: url('../images/QUOTE2.png');
  left: auto;
  right: 20%;
}
```

**Display**

Desired results are that (1) each of the dynamically rendered quotes align with the top of the content block, and (2) the quotes dynamically position with margin padding to the left and right of the content block as shown by the red arrows.
[image]

Comment: Whilst this can be done, wouldn't it be better to create them using css content property and :before and :after?

Comment: Ah. I am not familiar with those css styles. I will look into themm. Thanks @MightyPork

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseudo elements are perfect for this sort of thing.

HTML:

```
<div id='my_div'>
    <p>Content here.</p>
    <p>Etc.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#my_div {
    position: relative;
}
#my_div::before, #my_div::after {
    content: '';
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: url('path/to/open_quote_img.png');
    left: 5%;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
}
#my_div::after {
    background: url('path/to/close_quote_img.png');
    left: auto;
    right: 5%;
}
```

That code assumes your quote graphics are 50px in width and height - modify as required.

Finally, to ensure your content doesn't overlay the quote images, set an appropriate `padding-left` and `padding-right` on the container (in my example, the `div`) so the content is sufficiently pushed in away from them.

Comment: thank you @Utkanos I am going to try your answer and post back. This will be a good learning for me.

Comment: Something's not quite right about the styling @Utkanos. see my added info on my oq

Comment: p/s: Remember to use `::` instead of `:` for pseudo-elements. The latter is used for pseudo-classes, e.g. `:hover`.

Comment: @H.Ferrence - oops, I forgot the `left` / `top` styles - see amended answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Utkanos. That is closer and better. I can see it working with your solution. I just need to tweak the positioning to get the graphic images to align flush with the top of the text and then to bring the images in closer to the block content. Thank you very much for the solution. I learned some new things (which is one of the things I really like about posting to SO). Plus, I could not have solved this on my own with my current knowledge level of CSS3. Thanks again.

Comment: I am getting closer @Utkanos. Thank you for your help and suggestions. I have posted a new screen shot in my OQ based on what my CSS looks like at this time using your assistance.

Comment: You're welcome, @H.Ferrence. I'm afraid further tightening this solution so the quotes sit a set distance away from the start and end of the text's first and last lines, which is what your updated OQ appears to be describing as desired, will be tough. I've coded many of these quote things and, truth be told, the quotes are never *exactly* where I'd like them to be. Normally it's the closing quote's position that's hardest to get right. Two final bits: change `- 50px` to `- 18px` (half your image's height) and consider a `blockquote` tag rather than a `div` for this.

Comment: Although the results are not exactly what I was looking for, they are close enough so I am accepting this as the "best answer" at this time since there seems to not be a way in CSS3 to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is using `absolute` positioning inside a `relative` container. For example:

```css
.container { width:300px; position:relative;padding:20px}
    .left-quote {position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; font-size:30px;}
    .right-quote {position:absolute; bottom:20px; right:10px; font-size:30px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <span class="left-quote">"</span>
      <span class="right-quote">"</span>
      <p>is one of the smartest and most dedicated people that I know... he helped the company achieve incredible share of voice in key publications such as...</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am trying to use pseudo css but I looked closer at your answer @luke2012 and your ending quote appears after the content. I need the graphic to appear to the right of the content with a `vertical-align:top`